# Transition to SplitViewController displays right side content after animation is complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

My app has a `UISplitViewController` that it can display, but is not the rootViewController.  I have managed to get this working with one exception - the transition to the `UISplitViewController` is displaying the contents of its `UIWebView` after the animation completes.

In debug, I can see that the `UIWebView` is loaded prior to the animation.  In addition, the right side has a Navigation Bar and its title gets set at the same time the Web View is loaded, but unlike the web view, the navigation bar's title **does** appear during animation.

This is how I'm transitioning to the split view controller:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplitViewController"];
UINavigationController *leftNavController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
HelpLeftTableViewController *leftViewController = (HelpLeftTableViewController *)[leftNavController topViewController];
HelpRightViewController *rightViewController = [splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

leftViewController.selectionDelegate = rightViewController;
rightViewController.delegate = self;

[UIView transitionWithView:self.view.window
              duration:0.5
               options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                animations:^{
                    [rightViewController setHelpItem:helpItem];
                    [self presentViewController:splitViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
                }
            completion:nil];
```

The setHelpItem gives the right side its property from which to load the web view contents from during `viewDidLoad`.

Is there something I'm overlooking that is causing the `UIWebView` to not appear during animation?